# Favorite Folder doesn't show new messages until Mail Folder is expanded in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007 I'm having an issue where my Favorite Folders aren't showing new messages.

[image: Outlook Favorite Folders and Mail Folders]

When I start Outlook, my Mail Folders look like the pane on the left. The second Inbox Favorite folder doesn't show any new messages. But when I expand that account node in the Mail Folders section, suddenly it realizes that there are messages!

Any workarounds?

Comment: Would be nice to have the other account under my Mail Folders expanded by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figured out any workarounds. I manually expand the account folder every time Outlook starts.